# mismatched input 'OVERWRITE'. Expecting: 'INTO'

Tags: sql, hive, airflow, trino

I have a hive table with schema

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table`(
  `gpid` string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
  'wasbs://test@test.blob.core.windows.net/warehouse/test_data';
```

I am using airflow2 to add data into it. I need to override data each time job run so I tried using

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE default.temp_table
select id from sometable
```

but I am getting issue

> trino.exceptions.TrinoUserError: TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=SYNTAX_ERROR, message="line 1:8: mismatched input 'OVERWRITE'. Expecting: 'INTO'", query_id=20210817_140454_00001_rbuac)

Answer (score 3):

From [Trino Documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/appendix/from-hive.html):

By default, INSERT queries are not allowed to overwrite existing data. You can use the catalog session property `insert_existing_partitions_behavior` to allow overwrites. Prepend the name of the catalog using the Hive connector, for example hdfs, and set the property in the session before you run the insert query:

```
SET SESSION hdfs.insert_existing_partitions_behavior = 'OVERWRITE';
INSERT INTO hdfs.schema.table ...
```

The resulting behavior is equivalent to using `INSERT OVERWRITE` in Hive.

**Insert overwrite operation is not supported by Trino when the table is stored on S3, encrypted HDFS or an external location.** In such case deletebefore inserting.

Comment: I am storing data on azure blob storage. Also I have not specified any partition key, will it above in this case too?

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL I do not know... Just make backup table and try

Comment: Just confirming, it will not affect any global setting

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL Right. It will not affect any global settings